# Use C++ DLL library project in C++ /CLR project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, clr

I'm trying to use a unmanaged C++ DLL library project in a C++ /CLR managed  wrapper project, but because the unmanaged project uses `<thread>` the managed project won't build:
`error C1189: #error :  <thread> is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure.`

to be clear: the managed project itself does **NOT** use `<thread>`, only the referenced unmanaged

Is there anyway I can use threads in the unmanaged project and still have it interact properly with the managed wrapper project? (changing the project nature to use managed threads is not an option)

---

Edit: I received -2. I'm not sure why, I couldn't find anything for this specific case and I have no idea what is wrong exactly but it seems like the managed project is also compiling the unmanaged project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the include file for the unmanaged project include `<thread>`, directly or indirectly?  That's probably the cause of the error.

Try to make the interface header of the unmanaged project just define the interface, and not include any implementation-dependent include files.

Comment: the header of the native class being wrapped includes `<thread>`  because `thread` is a private member of that class. Any suggestions on how to hide it?

Comment: @WhiteNightFury: Could you hide some or all of the implementation details using PIMPL? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438477.aspx